# How to I set the max height of a SyntaxHighlighter code block both website-wide and for a single block of code?

Tags: javascript, css, syntax-highlighting, blogger, syntaxhighlighter

I'd like to both locally *and* globally set the max height of SyntaxHighlighter code blocks.

Here's an example of a global implementation that *sort of* works:

Once you get [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) implemented and working [per these instructions here](http://beendaved.blogspot.com/2015/03/working-with-syntax-highlighter-in.html), just before `</head>` in your Blogger template, add:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .syntaxhighlighter {
    height: 1024px;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    overflow-x: auto !important;}
</style>
```

([Source](http://www.queryadmin.com/1117/fixed-height-vertical-scrollbar-syntaxhighlighter-evolved/)). This will limit code size to 1024 vertical pixels, then add a vertical scrollbar to see the rest. This is great, but it does NOT set the *max* height, rather, it sets a *fixed* height. So, even if your code is only 4 lines long, it now makes the height 1024 pixels, pushing white space under your 4 lines and before the next thing appears on your post.

Notice below, for example. This is a temporary page on my website here: http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/p/test-page_19.html. You'll see a long block of code, which is fine, because it takes > 1024 vertical pixels to display, followed by 4 little lines of code, followed by a *ton* of white space, followed by the word "end" to indicate where the next item in the post appears.

1. I don't want all that white space--I want 1024 pixels to be a *maximum* height not a fixed value, and...
2. I want to have the option to set other, local max-height settings for individual code blocks. Ex: 1024 pixels should be a global maximum across my whole site, but maybe I want 350 pixels on a certain post for a different code block, followed by 500 pixels for the next code block, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

use  css style

max-height

```
.syntaxhighlighter {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    overflow-x: auto !important;
    max-height: 1024px;
}
```

Comment: So far so good! What about the locally-overriding specifications? Maybe I can just re-post this code right above each code block in an individual post, updating the `max-height` value for each block of code?

Comment: the style will apply to all divs with class  .syntaxhighlighter....you have other divs with different classes?

Comment: Web design is one of those areas I don't even know enough to understand your question. I'm googling "div" as we speak. My apologies for being so weak in this area.

Comment: I did a search for "div" in my site template, and I got 401 hits. I seem to have hundreds of classes.

Comment: when you added my style to your container...was all divs you would like to have max height affected? if not...find the class or id of the divs and apply style....if it has many class I would advice use an "id" instead of class because if you style a class, all divs with that class will be affected (including the ones you don't want to be affected)

Comment: yes, when I put that style within my blogger `<head>` `</head>` container, all SyntaxHighlighter blocks of code, marked by `<pre class="brush:cpp"> source code here </pre>`, for example, site-wide, are affected. I'd like to be able to apply the `max-height` parameter to individual `<pre> </pre>` source code blocks (highlighted by SyntaxHighlighter), but don't know how.

Comment: pre{max-height:100px;overflow:auto}

Comment: For my C++ code, I tried `<pre {max-height:50px;} class="brush:cpp"> code goes here </pre>`, and it didn't work.