# Is there a way to force line-wrap in SyntaxHighlighter code blocks?

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

I just began using [Alex Gorbatchev's SyntaxHighlighter 3.0.83](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) on [my website](http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/), per [these fantastic instructions here](http://beendaved.blogspot.com/2015/03/working-with-syntax-highlighter-in.html). Then, I [globally set a `max-height` of 1024 pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166519/how-to-i-set-the-max-height-of-a-syntaxhighlighter-code-block-both-website-wide) in order to keep long code blocks from being too tall, but **now I'd like to implement a "wrap-text" or "line-wrap" type feature to automatically wrap long lines while viewing. Is this possible?** I believe it used to be available as a feature, but isn't anymore (I think).

Here's a screenshot of a code block from [this temporary internet page](http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/p/test-page_19.html), for example. Notice how the comment extends well outside of (to the right of) the visible window. I'd like SyntaxHighlighter to force line-wrap instead of using the horizontal scroll-bar.

[image]

**If you're not familiar with SyntaxHighlighter:** since all that SyntaxHighlighter requires to do this pretty formatting is a pair of `<pre>` `</pre>` tags, such as this: `<pre> code goes here </pre>`, the HTML for the pretty-syntax-highlighted C++ source code you see in the screenshot above is simply this:

```
<pre class="brush:cpp">
//I am a long line of C++ source code; I just keep going on and on and on forever to the end of my days because my creator used line-wrapping in his text editor to write me and sometimes he likes long comments.
int myFunc()
{
  //do something
  return 1;
}
</pre>
```

That's it, plus a little bit in your website ([Blogger](https://www.blogger.com/home), for instance) Template, per the [installation instructions](http://beendaved.blogspot.com/2015/03/working-with-syntax-highlighter-in.html) I linked to above.

Any way to make SyntaxHighlighter line-wrap what it displays?

Comment: is this the link to your site? http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/p/test-page_19.html?

Comment: Yes that's my site. That particular link is to a test page though that will be deleted once I figure all this out.

Comment: and you want to wrap the text in which div?...

Comment: repzero, it sounds like you may be quite familiar with CSS but not with this SyntaxHighlighter tool I'm using. Please see the screenshot and HTML I just added to my question to show you what I'm doing to get this nice pretty output. Does this help?